# Как запустить два сайта в одном приложении Asp Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core, iis

Сабж. 
К примеру у меня есть 2 домена. `site1.com` и `site2.com`. С этим все ясно, на сервере в  каждой папке лежит свое приложение для каждого сайта и все работает. 
Но вот к примеру мне нужно что бы при заходе на `site1.com` и `site2.com` юзер попадал в
 одно приложение и оно обрабатывало запросы с двух сайтов. Вот примерно как на блог хостинге.
Юзер заходит на `site1.com` запрос попадает в контроллер, контроллер видит что запрос пришел с сайта `site1.com` делает запрос в бд и выдает тот контент который предназначен для сайта `site1.com`. Как это сделать в контроллере понятно. А как настроить маршрутизацию 2х сайтов на 1 приложение.
Я не уверен что так правильно делать.
 Но мне кажется так будет тратится меньше ресурсов чем 1 сайт -  1 приложение. 
Ну и на каком сервере это лучше(проще) реализовать, docker/iis/linux?

Comment: ИМХО, ошибочное утверждение про трату ресурсов. Вот вы разделили на два сайта, человек зашел на один, делает там что-то, в это время сайт 2 спит, не тратит особо ресурсы (пример с использованием IIS), вдруг человек решил зайти в админку, и загрузить там список клиентов (условно), в этот момент сайт1 отправляет запрос сайту 2, тот просыпается, и делает свою задачу. Ну а теперь тоже самое, но с одним целым сайтом - у вас постоянно в памяти висит один "монолит", часть которого даже может и не использоваться, но вы вечно ее грузите. Ну и о какой "меньшей трате" тут может идти речь?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну а если таких сайтов 100? Вот сейчас пустое приложение занимает 92мб ram а 100 сайтов уже 9200мб.

Comment: То, что вы описывается, в народе называется "Монолитная архитектура" и "Микросервисная архитектура". Почти любой крупный сайт сейчас строится по второму принципу. Вот и думайте, зря они это делают, или нет... Ну а вообще, если у вас сайт всего на 92мб рам, то думать о таком вам рановато...

Comment: По задумке все сайты однотипные. Как например ЖЖ они ведь наверняка не на каждый ЖЖ создается свое приложение.

Comment: Ну, вы говорите про несколько доменов, чего меня смущает. ЖЖ это один домен, но с субдоменами, то есть `1.site.com`, такой маршрут думаю сделать не сложно, но чтоб разные домены... ну не знаю) В любом случае, я вам не даю ответа, лишь говорю, что спорное утверждение, что монолит меньше ресурсов будет кушать, чем микросервис)

Comment: На ЖЖ можно свой домен прикрутить по этому привел его как пример.

Comment: Да, это возможно. Но это делается не в приложении, а уровнем выше, на хостинге, перенаправлением dns.